# The New "Reversal" Badge: A Potential Problem?

Tags: discussion, badges, abuse

I just saw a couple new [badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) have been added. One is called the ["Reversal" badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/41/reversal), and states the following:

> Provided answer of +20 score to a
>   question of -5 score. This badge can
>   be awarded multiple times.

One point of worry: wouldn't this drive people with highly voted answers to *downvote* a question that might otherwise be okay (or borderline) *just* to try and get a badge? Shouldn't there be an additional restriction that *you yourself* can't have downvoted the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your downvote only accounts for 1 out of AT LEAST 5 necessary.

That means that 4 others would have to also downvote it, making the power of your own downvote weaker. And if that question ever gets any up votes (we are all well aware of people giving out sympathy votes for downvoted material), it means you need yet another downvote to offset it to keep it towards the -5 range.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/reversal-and-pundit-badges/

**Edit** I should also note that getting that many upvotes on a question that could potentially hit -5 is pretty hard (it was my answer to a really bad question which led to the badge).

The biggest difficulty is in getting 20 people to spend an upvote on an answer to an otherwise terrible question. Usually once a question hits a certain amount of down votes, people will just skip over it and pay no attention to the answers inside.

Comment: OK, let's play a game =)... So let's say you gave an answer that's got 20+ votes, and the question is at -4. Let's also say that, upon first reading the question, you didn't feel strongly either way regarding voting. Isn't the existence of this badge going to tempt you towards downvoting?

Comment: In that instance, I believe pretty much everyone would at least consider it, and many probably would downvote. But, that question already had a net of 4 downvotes, so the one person with a really good answer, isn't the only one considering it bad. Essentially you could consider it a badge for a 20+ votes answer to a question with a net of 4 downvotes excluding your own. I wouldn't have a problem with that badge, so as implemented it is basically the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/174160-make-a-new-diamond-in-the-rough-badge

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone might try that, but they have only 1 vote (or there's another issue); so they can do very little to get it to -5.